# How to use 'where clause' for Timestamp teradata where the data is in format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.s'?

Tags: datetime, timestamp, teradata

I'm willing to filter a table based on a column which has the data in format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.s' as described in the question. Since this is not default timestamp format in teradata,so I tried to typecast.

So far I have tried following things :

`where column_name > ${VAL1}(Timestamp(1),Format'YYYY-MM-DDbHH:MI:SS.s(1)') and column_name < ${VAL2}(Timestamp(1),Format'YYYY-MM-DDbHH:MI:SS.s(1)')`

`where column_name > ${VAL1}(Timestamp(0),Format'YYYY-MM-DDbHH:MI:SS.s(1)') and column_name < ${VAL2}(Timestamp(0),Format'YYYY-MM-DDbHH:MI:SS.s(1)')`

`where column_name > ${Val1}(Timestamp(1),Format'YYYY-MM-DDbHH:MI:SS.s(1)bt') and column_name < ${Val2}(Timestamp(1),Format'YYYY-MM-DDbHH:MI:SS.s(1)bt')`

> But everytime the error is same "Syntax error,expected something like
>   an 'OR' keyword or ')' between an integer and the integer '13'.

I believe the problem is in passing the format to teradata. Any help appreciated.

P.S: VAL1 and VAL2 are bash variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the variables without quotes, e.g.

```
where column_name > 2019-03-04 12:34:56.7(Timestamp(1) ...
```

the parser treats `2019-03-04` as a calculation and stops at `13`.

Try

```
where column_name > '${VAL1}'(Timestamp(1) ...
```

And because this format *is* Teradata's default instead of casting to a timestamp you better use a literal:

```
where column_name > TIMESTAMP '${VAL1}' and column_name < TIMESTAMP '${VAL2}'
```

Comment: Hi, I got the issue resolved. Following were the errors:

1. Teradata sql assistant was showing format of the column wrong.
2. I used cast like this CAST('14/11/2012 16:24:18.071000' AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'dd/mm/yyyyBhh:mi:ss.s(6)') and that resolved the issue.

Apparently the above typecasting doesn't work. And it happened to be your answer in teradata forum which helped me. So, thanks.

Comment: SQL Assistant formats datetime values based on local settings, switch `Tools - Options - Data Format - Display dates in this format` to `YYYY-MM-DD`